# Power BI Desktop Import data from Facebook

Tags: facebook, powerbi

I build a COVID 19 dashboard and I try to get data from Social media Like Facebook to make a trend for example of how people search, Posts, comment about COVID 19, and so on. I follow the Microsoft document but the Connector disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The standard connecter in Power BI has been removed in the latest version. For older version of Power BI its not working. Part of this issue is due to the Facebook App permission restrictions. On the Microsoft Docs site it states:

*"Due to Facebook App permission restrictions, the connector capabilities described in this article are not currently working properly. We’re working with Facebook to return this functionality as soon as possible."*

The Facebook connector only looked at your posts and content, it cannot be used for seeing how people searched etc. You may have to use the Facebook Graph API to do this and another tool(s).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I try with Facebook Graph API but it gives me an error and can't seeing how people searched. can you help me of how I can do this with Facebook API? also i need with API another tool ??

Comment: Sorry I've not used the FB Graph API, just know that is what you would use. If you have questions about it please open another question for the subject facebook-graph-api tag. I would suggest outlining your question better to get a good response https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If I've answered your Power BI question please accept the answer.